# How to change log file from SystemOut.log to other in WAS.7

Tags: rad, websphere-7

In websphere application server.7 ,(WAS/RAD) , How to change the the logs that are storing in SystemOut.log file into other file ??

Is there any steps to change log file in logging and tracing??

Comment: Do you want to change the name of the SystemOut.log file, or do you want to move some of the log entries to another file?  If the latter, which log entries specifically do you want to move to another file?

Comment: Actually i want to move some logs that are logging in SystemOut.log to some other like Xyzexample.log . As systemOut.log is JVM log . logging many lines. I want few specific data to log in that Xyzexample.log...

Comment: I don't know how possible it is to reroute individual messages, but I'm not overly familiar with RAS.  It might be possible to do something with java.util.logging.Handler, but I don't know, sorry.